# sh shell for loop without seq

Tags: bash, for-loop, sh

I'm writing a script that must work in bash and sh and it runs on a miniscule platform and some things appear to be missing such as seq. All these limitations/requirements is making writing this script VERY difficult. I need to write a for loop that works under all these requirements.

This only works for bash:

```
for (( i = 0; i <= 4; i++ ))
do
  echo $i
done
```

This should work in sh, but the platform I'm using is apparently missing seq.

```
for i in $(seq 1 $INPUT); do
```

$INPUT is the max defined by the user.

Comment: @Joel, just check what is your /bin/sh stands for. E.g. on debian systems it is mostly linked to `dash` and `dash` doesn't support `for (())` contrsuction.

Answer (score 16):

Kids these days are so spoiled with their newfangled shell builtins.

```
i=1
while [ $i -le $INPUT ]; do
  echo $i
  i=$(expr $i + 1)
done
```

Comment: extra +1 for "cranky"

Comment: It's very likely the shell is at least POSIX-conforming, so you can use `i=$((i+1))` instead of `expr`.